Error extración de datos en Formula One API
Estoy tratando de scrapear en esta api de fórmula 1 URL: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/11586746/SztEa7bL#dfa298c3-bd29-4a40-9ea0-8cbd81653905
Trato de sacar los resultados de la temporada 2023 de la ronda 1
con este endpoint: http://ergast.com/api/f1/{{year}}/{{round}}/results
Y me da el error 400 (bad request ), proporciono el código en texto,
a ver si me podeis ayudar...
# PARTE 2 sacar datos de la puntuación por carrera de cada piloto
import requests

# Define el año y la ronda de la carrera que quieres consultar
year = "2022"

round = "1"

url2 = "http://ergast.com/api/f1/{{year}}/{{round}}/results"

response2 = requests.get(url2)
print(response2)

def obtener_puntuacion_piloto():

    if response2.status_code == 200:
        print("Petición exitosa!")
        print(response.text)  
    
    
    else:
        print("Error 400: Bad Request. Revisar parámetros y la estructura de la URL.")
        print("Respuesta del servidor:", response.text) #Esto puede dar más pistas sobre el error
        
    
    else:
        print("Error:", response2.status_code)

Quiero sacar los resultados de la primera ronda de la temporada de 2023 de Formula 1

Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Para comenzar, si estás ejecutando un API que te devuelve datos, yo no llamaría a eso scrapear (verbo que no existe, por cierto). Luego, sin importar el error que te devuelva el get, tú imprimes un "Error 400", por lo que no sabes si realmente has recibido un error 400 o cuá, pero para diagnosticar el error, habría que comenzar por saber cuál fue, por lo que sería mejor que indiques en tu pregunta cuál es el status_code de la respuesta y el mensaje de error que realmente obtienes del servidor.

Por cierto, veo que usas la cadena "http://ergast.com/api/f1/{{year}}/{{round}}/results" tal cual, como URL. Pero, supongo que {{year}} es un placeholder para el año y {{round}} lo es para la ronda, por lo que debieras enviar una cadena tipo: "http://ergast.com/api/f1/2023/1/results". También es común que las API's requieran algún token que se derive del inicio de sesión y/o alguna llave que te de acceso a la información. Lee la documentación del API que estás tratando de usar para determinar qué necesitas enviar como parte del request.
